# Testing in case of TLS 1.3 with AES-GCM

Tags: tls, sniffing, automated-testing, replay-detection

At work, I'm used to sniffing and capturing on network interfaces by which client and server intercom on LAN in my domain so as to grab genuine business data, followed by my customized *replaying* to auto-testing business processing logic of certain software repeatedly.

This is what I know to be a classic bottom-up method in software testing methodologies. But such practice turns out hard when TLS protocol is enrolled and even so for TLS v1.3, which is well-known for its *forward secrecy* feature.

I believe this frustrates most of us testing engineers, for that no alternative based on sniffing-and-capturing apparatus yet to be disclosed in case of TLS v1.3 based client and server software. Am I right?

I'd like to hear from the community if this makes sense.

Comment: *"I believe this frustrates most of us ... Am I right?"* - I don't see any question here apart from asking about opinions, which is explicitly off-topic. Surely, if the traffic is encrypted then simply sniffing plain traffic for analysis is no longer possible and you need to adjust how you do testing. But the details on how to change  depend on what you actually need to test.

Comment: *"I believe this frustrates most of us testing engineers"* - I believe it doesn't. The most test engineers don't send *random* data and don't expect, without any reason, that the answer will be the same as the intercepted one. Instead, the most test engineers use **deterministic** tests. They use *specific* data and expect to obtain back *specific* answers. This question has nothing to do with security. It is about testing methodology.

Comment: Hmm I smell an intelligence agency

Comment: @mentallurg Surely if I could. Nevertheless, in case of third-party distribution this is, what I believe, a very common way for software testing in aim of robustness under CHAOS conditions (Netflix did that).

Comment: Netflix did other thing. They intentionally provoked failures to check if they will be handled by the system correctly. Chaos Engineering may be one of the approaches. But it is relevant for a small very specific part of testing, where you say *"most of us testing engineers"*. Your generalization is not true. If testing is not relevant, for your question, I'd suggest you to remove anything related to testing from your question. If you question is "How can I decrypt intercepted TLS 1.3 traffic?", then please ask exactly this question.

Comment: @Sir Muffingon lol I like it thanks.

Comment: @mentallurg and for deterministic test that most do, I'm not part of it. My experience is, "no one could ever expects complex system to output anything without running". Be heuristic, and you will need to sniff and replay.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks and "you need to adjust how you do testing" - I wish I could.